Isekai manga where the main character gets to choose his new mother
The main character dies and was given a selection of women to pick as his mother.
As a kid he ended up overusing his magic and could only use magic scrolls.

Could this be Drawing: Saikyou Mangaka wa Oekaki Skill de Isekai Musou Suru! (Drawing: The Greatest Mangaka Becomes a Skilled "Martial Artist" in Another World)?

Angry at his mother for asking him to send her some money, he died in a car accident. He was given a chance to choose his new mother and reincarnate in another world.
Akira, not wanting to have a repeat of his past life, decided to choose an ordinary but safe life... He was reincarnated as Akira, the only son of a magic store, with his previous life's memories. He had no talent for swordsmanship or magic, but he didn't care as his family still loved him. At one point, he realized that he could embody various things by "drawing a picture". That's when he noticed his cheat ability...!?

If you use up all of your mana, you get stuck having to use scrolls.

